# Account for Sandbox

Tags: paypal

I've followed the [PayPal APIs Getting Started Guide](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/paypal-apis-getting-started-guide) and implemented the example in PHP. But no matter what I do I always get this back:

```
Array
(
    [responseEnvelope] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 2013-03-21T16:01:41.027-07:00
            [ack] => Failure
            [correlationId] => f24ca862fa014
            [build] => 5343121
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [errorId] => 520003
                    [domain] => PLATFORM
                    [subdomain] => Application
                    [severity] => Error
                    [category] => Application
                    [message] => Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
                )

        )

)
```

And, indeed, it seems that my API credentials are incorrect. If I try the same code with some API credentials I've found in some PHP samples I downloaded from the site everything works fine.

Why does my PayPal profile generate API credentials that are not valid? What do I need to do in order to get a valid API key?

Comment: If you can provide the test sandbox API credentials, I can take a look at the account and see what the issue may be.  Make sure that you are also using the test application id as well with your credentials.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad - See my edit. If you need full signature I don't mind e-mailing it to you or something, but I don't think I should post it here.

Comment: The username just allows me to look up the account on my end, and the credentials allows me to run the same test you are against the same account to see what the issue is.  If you would like, you can open up a ticket with PayPal MTS here and provide your SANDBOX credentials so that we can look into the issue.  Then let me know the ticket number.  You should NEVER provide your LIVE credentials, as these would be for your live account.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad Assuming you meant [this](https://ppmts.custhelp.com): `#130322-000279`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your ticket and I get the same error.  From looking at what you provided, it appears that you are using the wrong credentials.  You are trying to connect with the sandbox, but have you set up a developer account and within that account set up a test sandbox seller and buyer account?  If you have not done this, you will need to do this to be able to test with the sandbox.  It appears that you are using live credentials to try to test with on the sandbox, which will not work.

Comment: I discovered this right before you posted your answer. Sorry for wasting everybody's time but it's a basic piece of info I had not been able to find in the 20+ info page's I had read so far.

Answer (score 0):

The API credentials you can find in your PayPal profile (apparently) cannot be used to develop stuff in the Sandbox. You need to log into [PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com) (with your regular PayPal account) and create [virtual test accounts](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox). One of those virtual test users needs to be of **Business** type and have the same e-mail that your real PayPal account. Then, it'll be assigned some virtual test API credentials—*those* are the API credentials you need to use!

Comment: That doesn't work. Sandbox now won't even allow you to create an account with the same email address as your main account. Maybe if you have a separate developer account but I'm canadian and our regular account and developer accounts are the same.